# How does one access and modify the content of site pages using the SharePoint 2013 Rest API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

Basically I have a ribbon custom action and I would like to put it in page actions. When the user clicks on it it accesses the HTML content of the page and modifies it in order to give for instance definitions of a word.

What commands with the REST API can I use to simply retrieve the HTML content and what commands can I use to update it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Office 365 Development Patterns & Practices has a module that discusses updating wiki pages: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Scenarios/Provisioning.Pages

Comment: He explains how to add/modify a site page but he doesn't explain how to get the html code of a site page...